# How can I hide or show a bootstrap modal in my web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, bootstrap-modal

I'm new at web programming and trying to figure out modal structure. The point is , my modal is always open even if I refresh the page. I want it to be activated after user clicks a submitting button.

Sory for long codes but I'm using a Colorlib template to make some practice. I didn't design the all form page by myself. Can you examine the code and tell me what is wrong with the bootstrap model? Why it is shown in the beginning, at the top of the page? I tried with different pages and it was working well.

HTML Code :

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="page-wrapper bg-gra-03 p-t-45 p-b-50">
    <div class="wrapper wrapper--w790">
        <div class="card card-5">
            <div class="card-heading">
                <h2 class="title">PROJENİZ VE KENDİNİZ HAKKINDA BİLGİ VERİNİZ</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form method="post" action="/proje_ekle">
                    <div class="form-row m-b-55">
                        <div class="name">İsminiz ve<br>Soy İsminiz</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <div class="row row-space">
                                <div class="col-2">
                                    <div class="input-group-desc">
                                        <input class="input--style-5" type="text" name="first_name">
                                        <span class="asterisk_input"> </span>
                                        <label class="label--desc">isim</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2">
                                    <div class="input-group-desc">
                                        <input class="input--style-5" type="text" name="last_name">
                                        <span class="asterisk_input"> </span>
                                        <label class="label--desc">soy isim</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">Şirketiniz</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search">
                                        <select name="company_name">
                                            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Şirketinizi Seçiniz
                                            </option>
                                            <option>Maxion</option>
                                            <option>IGYA</option>
                                            <option>İnci Holding</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <span class="asterisk_input"> </span>
                                        <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">Departmanınız</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <!-- <input class="input--style-5" type="text" name="department_name"> -->
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search">
                                        <select name="department_name">
                                            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Departmanınızı seçiniz
                                            </option>
                                            <option>Bilgi Teknolojileri</option>
                                            <option>İnsan Kaynakları</option>
                                            <option>Mali İşler</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <span class="asterisk_input"> </span>
                                        <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">Projenizin İsmi</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="input--style-5" type="text" name="project_name">
                                <span class="asterisk_input"> </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">Projenizin Kategorisi</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search">
                                        <select name="project_category">
                                            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Projenizin Kategorisini
                                                Seçiniz
                                            </option>
                                            <option>ARGE</option>
                                            <option>Mühendislik</option>
                                            <option>İmalat</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <span class="asterisk_input"> </span>
                                        <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">Projenizin Açıklaması</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <textarea cols="40" rows="3" class="input--style-5" type="text"
                                    name="project_explanation"></textarea>
                                <span class="asterisk_input"> </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>




                    <div class="form-row p-t-20">


                        <div class="input-group custom-file-button">
                            <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupFile">Proje Dosyaları Ekle</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputGroupFile" multiple>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--red" type="submit">Projemi Kütüphaneye Kaydet</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Codes :

```
/* ==========================================================================
   #FONT
   ========================================================================== */
.font-robo {
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.font-poppins {
  font-family: "Poppins", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.font-opensans {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #GRID
   ========================================================================== */
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row .col-2:last-child .input-group-desc {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.row-space {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-refine {
  margin: 0 -15px;
}

.row-refine .col-3 .input-group-desc,
.row-refine .col-9 .input-group-desc {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.col-2 {
  width: -webkit-calc((100% - 30px) / 2);
  width: -moz-calc((100% - 30px) / 2);
  width: calc((100% - 30px) / 2);
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.form-row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.form-row .name {
  width: 125px;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.form-row .value {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 125px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 125px);
  width: calc(100% - 125px);
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .form-row {
    display: block;
  }
  .form-row .name,
  .form-row .value {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .form-row .name {
    margin-bottom: 7px;
  }
}

.col-3,
.col-9 {
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.col-3 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 25%;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-3 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 35%;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 35%;
    flex: 0 0 35%;
    max-width: 35%;
  }
}

.col-9 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 75%;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 75%;
  flex: 0 0 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-9 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 65%;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 65%;
    flex: 0 0 65%;
    max-width: 65%;
  }
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #BOX-SIZING
   ========================================================================== */

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #RESET
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * A very simple reset that sits on top of Normalize.css.
 */
body,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
blockquote, p, pre,
dl, dd, ol, ul,
figure,
hr,
fieldset, legend {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Remove trailing margins from nested lists.
 */
li > ol,
li > ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/**
 * Remove default table spacing.
 */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Reset Chrome and Firefox behaviour which sets a `min-width: min-content;`
 *    on fieldsets.
 */
fieldset {
  min-width: 0;
  /* [1] */
  border: 0;
}

button {
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #PAGE WRAPPER
   ========================================================================== */
.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 13px;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #BACKGROUND
   ========================================================================== */
.bg-blue {
  background: #2c6ed5;
}

.bg-red {
  background: #fa4251;
}

.bg-gra-01 {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#fbc2eb), to(#a18cd1));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #fbc2eb 0%, #a18cd1 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #fbc2eb 0%, #a18cd1 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #fbc2eb 0%, #a18cd1 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #fbc2eb 0%, #a18cd1 100%);
}

.bg-gra-02 {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, from(#fc2c77), to(#6c4079));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom left, #fc2c77 0%, #6c4079 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom left, #fc2c77 0%, #6c4079 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom left, #fc2c77 0%, #6c4079 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #fc2c77 0%, #6c4079 100%);
}

.bg-gra-03 {
  /* background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, from(#08aeea), to(#b721ff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom left, #08aeea 0%, #b721ff 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom left, #08aeea 0%, #b721ff 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom left, #08aeea 0%, #b721ff 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #08aeea 0%, #b721ff 100%); */
background-image: url(/images/form_images/form_resim.jpg);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #SPACING
   ========================================================================== */
.p-t-100 {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.p-t-130 {
  padding-top: 130px;
}

.p-t-180 {
  padding-top: 180px;
}

.p-t-45 {
  padding-top: 45px;
}

.p-t-20 {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.p-t-15 {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.p-t-10 {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.p-t-30 {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.p-b-100 {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.p-b-50 {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.m-r-45 {
  margin-right: 45px;
}

.m-r-55 {
  margin-right: 55px;
}

.m-b-55 {
  margin-bottom: 55px;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #WRAPPER
   ========================================================================== */
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper--w960 {
  max-width: 960px;
}

.wrapper--w790 {
  max-width: 790px;
}

.wrapper--w780 {
  max-width: 780px;
}

.wrapper--w680 {
  max-width: 680px;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #BUTTON
   ========================================================================== */
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.btn--radius {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.btn--radius-2 {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn--pill {
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.btn--green {
  background: #57b846;
}

.btn--green:hover {
  background: #4dae3c;
}

.btn--blue {
  background: #4272d7;
}

.btn--blue:hover {
  background: #3868cd;
}

.btn--red {

  background: #1a1a1a;
  
}

.btn--red:hover {
  background: #b31515;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #DATE PICKER
   ========================================================================== */
td.active {
  background-color: #2c6ed5;
}

input[type="date" i] {
  padding: 14px;
}

.table-condensed td, .table-condensed th {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.daterangepicker td {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
}

.daterangepicker {
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.daterangepicker::after, .daterangepicker::before {
  display: none;
}

.daterangepicker thead tr th {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.daterangepicker .table-condensed th select {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #FORM
   ========================================================================== */
input {
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.radio-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #666;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.radio-container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.radio-container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

.radio-container .checkmark:after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #57b846;
}

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* input[required]{
  background-image: radial-gradient(#F00 30%, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(#F00 15%, transparent 16%);
  background-size: 1em 1em;
  background-position: right top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
} */


.asterisk_input::after {
  content:" *"; 
  color: #e32;
  position: absolute; 
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -15px; 
  font-size: large; 
  padding: 0 5px 0 0; }

.input--style-5 {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  line-height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 22px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #555;
}

.input-group-desc {
  position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .input-group-desc {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
}

.input-group {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.label {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.label--block {
  width: 100%;
}

.label--desc {
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: block;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 7px;
  left: 0;
}




#inputGroupFile{


  position:relative; 
  top:1.2em;
  font-size: 0.8em ;
  color: #b31515;



}
```

JavaScript Codes :

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    /*==================================================================
        [ Daterangepicker ]*/
    try {
        $('.js-datepicker').daterangepicker({
            "singleDatePicker": true,
            "showDropdowns": true,
            "autoUpdateInput": false,
            locale: {
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
            },
        });
    
        var myCalendar = $('.js-datepicker');
        var isClick = 0;
    
        $(window).on('click',function(){
            isClick = 0;
        });
    
        $(myCalendar).on('apply.daterangepicker',function(ev, picker){
            isClick = 0;
            $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    
        });
    
        $('.js-btn-calendar').on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
    
            if(isClick === 1) isClick = 0;
            else if(isClick === 0) isClick = 1;
    
            if (isClick === 1) {
                myCalendar.focus();
            }
        });
    
        $(myCalendar).on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            isClick = 1;
        });
    
        $('.daterangepicker').on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    
    
    } catch(er) {console.log(er);}
    /*[ Select 2 Config ]
        ===========================================================*/
    
    try {
        var selectSimple = $('.js-select-simple');
    
        selectSimple.each(function () {
            var that = $(this);
            var selectBox = that.find('select');
            var selectDropdown = that.find('.select-dropdown');
            selectBox.select2({
                dropdownParent: selectDropdown
            });
        });
    
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    

})(jQuery);

if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
}
```

Comment: Did you include bootstrap's JS and CSS scripts in your HTML? And I can't find a button or event listener to toggle the modal? Assuming Bootstrap V5.2, [look here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/). Jsfiddle with working modal: (added a button and id to the modal) https://jsfiddle.net/v97ot23w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like any CSS or JS is hiding the modal. Why would it be hidden?

There should be some CSS like:

```
.modal {
  display: none;
}
.modal.active {
  display: block; // or flex, grid, whatever you need
}
```

Then the triggering button needs an event listener, listening for a `'click'` event, which will add the class `active` to the modal. To "close" the modal you need to remove the class "active" in another event listener.